# Muon does not apply changes

Tags: apt, muon-package-manager

After updating muon does not ask for password, it only pops up a notification: **can not continue due to invalid identification**.
I have to use `apt-get` to install one-by-one of my selections.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix it, but one alternative option is switch to Synaptic Pakage Manager, instead of Muon.